# How to submit data to Google forms with Java (jsoup or other)

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to submit data from Java to a Google form. Using JSoup and the following code I can't achieve this goal. I've tried several different methods and I've searched for few days with still no result. My last resort is to bug some intelligent people on Stackoverflow. Can anybody help me?

```
    String url = "http://docs.google.com/forms/d/1OEBmIXG-enn3Yb48JKfRHjHFsTnGUZkIR_7KHR_raF0/viewform";

    try {
        Jsoup.connect(url)
                .data("entry.1278622432", "reply")
                .data("entry.1578309861", "reply")
                //.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                .post();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=405, URL=http://doc
```

Html error code:

> 10.4.6 405 Method Not Allowed
>
> The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource.

(Solution doesn't have to be with JSoup.)

Comment: So, what happens, what did you expect?

Comment: Do you know Selenium webdriver? My suggestion is to use it. It works better. Just search for Selenium webdriver with java and you will get plenty of help on this.

Comment: I've updated the explanation a bit. Forgot to mention the error result. @ABP: Going to try it now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a post on the view form URL. When submitting this form from the browser, what it does is:

```
curl \
'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1OEBmIXG-enn3Yb48JKfRHjHFsTnGUZkIR_7KHR_raF0/formResponse' \
-H 'Host: docs.google.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' \
-H 'Accept-Language: nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'DNT: 1' \
-H 'Referer: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1OEBmIXG-enn3Yb48JKfRHjHFsTnGUZkIR_7KHR_raF0/viewform' \
-H 'Cookie: GDS_PREF=hl=en_US; __utma=184632636.34...1517515.2; PREF=ID=4922e3....:FF=0:LD=nl:TM=1380883655:LM=1381731571:S=JvyU_OhlkQ7rE3x3; NID=67=hy29...sglz4PVeS53BZ4eLkYK_wDm9-jmdj7apqNZv6rEwUPDobxjagtLN5gpl4A7v0oA' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data 'entry.1278622432=&entry.1578309861=&draftResponse=%5B%5D%0D%0A&pageHistory=0&fbzx=-5804634750901421753'
```

(thanks FireBug!) so that's what you'll have to emulate. Starting with the post to .../formResponse

Comment: Amazingly simple solution. Thank you so much. I'm kicking myself for wasting so much time!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then import the following packages

```
 import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
 import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
 import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
```

Change the following code snippet accordingly

```
 String url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/" + FORM_ID + "/formResponse?" + metaData +
            "&draftResponse=%5B%5D%0D%0A&pageHistory=0&fbzx=-5804634750901421753";

 Client client = Client.create();
 WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
 ClientResponse response =webResource
                    .accept("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
                    .header("Host", "docs.google.com")
                    .header("User-Agent", " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) " +
                            "Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0")
                    .header("Accept-Encoding", " gzip, deflate")
                    .header("Accept-Language", "nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3")
                    .header("DNT", 1)
                    .header("Referer", "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/" + FORM_ID + "/viewform")
                    .header("Cookie", "GDS_PREF=hl=en_US; __utma=184632636.34...1517515.2; PREF=ID=4922e3....:FF=0:LD=nl:TM=1380883655:LM=1381731571:S=JvyU_OhlkQ7rE3x3; NID=67=hy29...sglz4PVeS53BZ4eLkYK_wDm9-jmdj7apqNZv6rEwUPDobxjagtLN5gpl4A7v0oA")
                    .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .header("cookie", "S=spreadsheet_forms=ay7KL1tRTlqur9RqEdI6mxMF6vx3FcsM; CONSENT=YES+LK.en+20180304-09-0; SEARCH_SAMESITE=CgQI5Y4B; HSID=ADSwbqJPF1Qr-Ec-y; SSID=A4q87SuvNBKdb2ple; APISID=gkfURe1KHD3JK_Sw/AEHh8huA9FCjME_AH; SAPISID=BYtObLGnVKKbphJu/AOOdACYgOk7aPfh5h; __Secure-HSID=ADSwbqJPF1Qr-Ec-y; __Secure-SSID=A4q87SuvNBKdb2ple; __Secure-APISID=gkfURe1KHD3JK_Sw/AEHh8huA9FCjME_AH; __Secure-3PAPISID=BYtObLGnVKKbphJu/AOOdACYgOk7aPfh5h; S=billing-ui-v3=qCH3rMDDCaZ_xpidA_rUzezuzbz9IcRd:billing-ui-v3-efe=qCH3rMDDCaZ_xpidA_rUzezuzbz9IcRd:adwords-navi=FttYNTeVNckYg7X8E3ZsxsJ1vM7Zsbb1; SID=tQdHP8MAb80SUf_M7LebR0rky_mob9y0tekyqkfTiK6WCjtIptZqkRG_2zw8vDx7Wyelow.; __Secure-3PSID=tQdHP8MAb80SUf_M7LebR0rky_mob9y0tekyqkfTiK6WCjtIaTSJ2pBkmZ-zBBINW3RhYw.; S=billing-ui-v3=qCH3rMDDCaZ_xpidA_rUzezuzbz9IcRd:billing-ui-v3-efe=qCH3rMDDCaZ_xpidA_rUzezuzbz9IcRd:adwords-navi=FttYNTeVNckYg7X8E3ZsxsJ1vM7Zsbb1:explorer=IK1XkkO0xKJk5bU2F52cs0z1t8mXK5v1; NID=197=rBl9xBCn7YlyxrnqcHF35435sGtnCn6dSss6tr6EPfswg19EFOKGJz_upr5qLgJ922wl0G6ufAnILvoUMx1Csvg9ddVMJE65ALGlSm2u4ERtePDrka2yLQE4XQGvX6WXGNJz9e7HFSmWZTOGD_f0wA2BudviRAbKxqUyPHPxR_uhqAH-andEJDUdosDmuGRg27JKl_IyEd98qlEd-2c_rNx06tE7BnjBkW66v-XB-AGZP0610_JSW2fzemYTPuPC2ZL3iFTFFF4fPP5rhhoNCM2GApidF9yG0hxKFBbTLLphy4IvTl8gBkj10l-DZS_Njr6A8uCts1RfaGL5aq8-yz1IRKEANrheizBWCYNioi1bmgeBl_89WJyYCVfYROBHbPQW0blRimGX4Ql4wcM; 1P_JAR=2020-2-12-4; SIDCC=AN0-TYtB0dfkjw4QetRyEiIaeRH9MuEXLmZe5C8w55MLe8EK_1P0ktruhGOZaXInzu_VfIjkQ8K3")
                    .get(ClientResponse.class);
```